# How to stop a Javascript Timer after the second countdown?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Pomodoro clock (A countdown timer for 25-minutes of productivity and a 5-minute countdown of break time), and I am having trouble stopping the break time countdown.

Here's the Javascript I have so far:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);

            var breakClock = function() {
                 $("#title").text(function(i, text){
       return text === 'Breaktime' ? 'Productive Countdown' : 'Breaktime'
            }); 

             var fiveMinutes = 60 * .05,
                  display = document.querySelector('#time');
             startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);

             if (--timer < 0) {
                  clearInterval(this.countdown);
             }

            };

          breakClock();  
          }
    }, 500);
}                  
$(".startClock").click(function(){
    var twentyfiveMinutes = 60 * .25,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(twentyfiveMinutes, display);
});
```

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/cenjennifer/pen/pjzBVy?editors=101

FYI: I reduce the time so that I can easily test the functionality.

Comment: Have you looked into clearTimeout(id)?

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
clearInterval(this.countdown);
```

to:

```
clearInterval(countdown);
```

the `this` keyword is not needed as the `countdown` variable is a local variable of the  parent scope of the `breakClock()` function.

Comment: You say it's not _needed_, maybe you should be a little more strict on the fact that it's simply wrong?

Comment: I've actually tried to use clearInterval(countdown) originally, and it didn't work as well.