# Reducing Repetitive Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript

Related to this previous Question: [How to stop a Javascript Timer after the second countdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301739/how-to-stop-a-javascript-timer-after-the-second-countdown/32301763#32301763)

I figured out a way for my Pomodoro clock to function properly, but my code is pretty repetitive. I couldn't figure out a way to not recreate the same (or very similar function) without the second break timer continuously running. Any ideas?

```
   function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

  var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        //minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      $(".startClock").click(function () {
          clearInterval(countdown);
        }); 
        if (--timer < 0) {
              clearInterval(countdown);
              breakClock();
              }
    }, 500);
  } 

  function breakTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

  var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        //minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      $(".startClock").click(function () {
          clearInterval(countdown);
        }); 
        if (--timer < 0) {
              clearInterval(countdown);  
              }
    }, 500);

  $("body").css("background-color", "#E13F86");             

  $("#title").text(function(i, text){
       return text === 'Breaktime' ? 'Productive Countdown' : 'Breaktime'
            });
   } 

  var display = document.querySelector('#time');

  function startClock() {
            var twentyfiveMinutes = 60 * .25;
            startTimer(twentyfiveMinutes, display);

  }

  function breakClock() {
            var fiveMinutes = 60 * .05;
            breakTimer(fiveMinutes, display);    
  }

  $(".startClock").on("click", function() {
   startClock();

  });
```

Here's my codepen as well: http://codepen.io/cenjennifer/pen/pjzBVy?editors=101

Comment: If this is functioning code that you want feedback on how to improve the code, then this question belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: *Hint:* The only diferences in the `countdown` functions are the call to `breakClock()`, you can use a Boolean parameter and an `if-statement` to control that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. jfriend00 is right, this code does belong on the code review page.

But since I'm here, I will give some feedback. Make an object (using function(){}), and put all of your functions inside of the object.

Instead of recreating all your variables in each function, make them properties inside of the object, so that they are accessible to all of the functions, and so that you don't need to keep recreating them. (Variables like timer, hour, minutes, should be moved as object properties).

Also, don't use global variables, they can interfere with libraries you may find to be useful later on. You should namespace, so that the code is more organized, and does not get overwritten by other globals.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to reuse the function, is to share the timer returned by setInterval and provide a callback in the startTimer function (used for both start and break). The callback, if provided, takes care of the code to run after the timer finishes. Therefore the specific code can be omitted from startTimer. Also since the timer is shared, no matter when started, the original loop can be stopped when called again (the button is clicked again), so that too can be omitted from the startTimer function, thus making it ready for reusability. The whole would look something like:

```
var currentcountdown;
var display = document.querySelector('#time');

function startTimer(duration, callback) {
      var timer = parseInt(duration), minutes, seconds;
      clearInterval(currentcountdown);
      currentcountdown = setInterval(function () {

        minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        seconds = Math.floor(timer % 60);

        //minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;    

        if (--timer < 0) {
              clearInterval(currentcountdown);
              if(callback)
                callback();              
              }
    }, 500);
} 


function startClock() {
            $("body").css("background-color", "black");
            $("#title").text('Productive Countdown');
            var twentyfiveMinutes = 60 * .25;
            startTimer(twentyfiveMinutes, breakClock);            
}

function breakClock() {
            $("body").css("background-color", "#E13F86");
            $("#title").text('Breaktime');
            var fiveMinutes = 60 * .05;
            startTimer(fiveMinutes);    
}

$(".startClock").on("click", function() {
   startClock();
});
```

As mentioned in the other post, synthetic sugar would be to put all values into objects (such as duration/background/title) and optionally put the timer and its variables (display/timer) into an object, but for straight forward re-usability of the function the above should provide a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and code! Everything makes a lot of sense. I'll be more mindful of the callback functionality.